# Convert XmlSlurper GPathResult to JSON string

Tags: json, grails, groovy, xml-serialization

After doing a lot of Googling.....

Is there an "easy way" of converting XMLSlurper results (GPathResult) to JSON?

I have added a sample XML file which I want to fetch server side, store it in a DB (JSON) and dump to a browser page for javascript processing...

Thanks!

Sander

See the following XML file.....:

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"> 
  <opensearch:Query searchTerms="tt0137523"/> 
  <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults> 
  <movies> 
    <movie> 
      <popularity>3</popularity> 
      <translated>true</translated> 
      <language>en</language>
      <original_name>Fight Club</original_name> 
      <name>Fight Club</name> 
      <alternative_name>El club de la lucha</alternative_name> 
      <type>movie</type> 
      <id>550</id> 
      <imdb_id>tt0137523</imdb_id> 
      <url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/550</url> 
      <overview>A lonely, isolated thirty-something young professional seeks an escape from his mundane existence with the help of a devious soap salesman. They find their release from the prison of reality through underground fight clubs, where men can be what the world now denies them. Their boxing matches and harmless pranks soon lead to an out-of-control spiral towards oblivion.</overview> 
      <votes>15</votes>
      <rating>8.2</rating> 
      <certification>R</certification> 
      <released>1999-09-16</released> 
      <runtime>138</runtime> 
      <categories>
        <category type="genre" name="Crime" url="http://themoviedb.org/genre/crime" id="80"/>
        <category type="genre" name="Drama" url="http://themoviedb.org/genre/drama" id="18"/>
        <category type="genre" name="Thriller" url="http://themoviedb.org/genre/thriller" id="53"/>
      </categories>
      <images> 
        <image type="poster" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/f84/4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84/fight-club-mid.jpg" size="mid" id="4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84"/> 
        <image type="poster" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/f84/4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84/fight-club-cover.jpg" size="cover" id="4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84"/> 
        <image type="poster" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/f84/4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84/fight-club-thumb.jpg" size="thumb" id="4bc908ae017a3c57fe002f84"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f55/4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55/fight-club-original.jpg" size="original" id="4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f55/4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55/fight-club-poster.jpg" size="poster" id="4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f55/4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55/fight-club-thumb.jpg" size="thumb" id="4bc908a8017a3c57fe002f55"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f51/4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51/fight-club-original.jpg" size="original" id="4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f51/4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51/fight-club-poster.jpg" size="poster" id="4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f51/4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51/fight-club-thumb.jpg" size="thumb" id="4bc908a6017a3c57fe002f51"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f4d/4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d/fight-club-original.jpg" size="original" id="4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f4d/4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d/fight-club-poster.jpg" size="poster" id="4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d"/> 
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/f4d/4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d/fight-club-thumb.jpg" size="thumb" id="4bc908a5017a3c57fe002f4d"/> 
      </images> 
      <version>8</version>
      <last_modified_at>2010-04-26 23:08:53</last_modified_at> 
    </movie> 
  </movies> 
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Comment: Do you have an example piece of xml?  What do you intend to do with attributes?

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? especially given the attributes on the opensearch:Query, category and image elements. JSON doesn't really have a concept like that.

Comment: { images: { image: [type:"poster], image: type...........

Comment: Using: <var> = org.json.XML.toJSONObject(url.text).OpenSearchDescription

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Grails, you might take a look at Grails Converters.

[Grails Converters](http://grails.org/Converters%20Reference)

They offer a quick way of consuming api XMLs and converting them to JSON.